# How do i write English alphabet in three or four lines?

Tags: html, css

i want to draw three or four lines to show proper formation of lowercase alphabet letters to teach children in my website. Please any body tell me how can i do for tracing four lines & writing letters on them.

```css
table,th,td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
text-decoration:overline underline line-through;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>kids</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>boys</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>girls</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
```

Comment: Man, I have no idea what you mean!

Comment: I think he wants to do this: http://i.imgur.com/E12KmKu.jpg

Comment: I think this will be best done with an image in your case rather than trying to mess around with CSS although that would be more scalable in the future and allow for new words etc

Comment: yes i agree with Rocket Hazmat, that's what i want, but in html table with text-decoration because i can't use an image

Comment: Updated my answer. May I ask why you took away the accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a Monospaced font like courier (each of them will use the same space), it will make background-lines easier to draw at the right place.

to play with :  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZgMMK

Think of a safe fall back if font not avalaible. you may take a look here http://www.cssfontstack.com/ (among other links that can be found on search engines)

```css
div {
  padding:1em 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, white, white 3.5em, red 3.5em, red 3.7em, transparent 3.7em),repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 3.7em, gray 3.7em, gray 3.9em, white 3.9em, white 8.186em)
}
p {
  white-space:nowrap;
  letter-spacing:0em;
  font-family:courier;
  height:1.2em;
  font-size:3.7em;
  text-indent:1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 0.05em, transparent 0.05em, transparent  0.5em ) 0 0 repeat ; 
  background-size:auto 0.42em;
  line-height:1.2em;
  
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  background-size:auto 0.28em;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.lc p {
  font-family: 'lucida console', courier;
```

```html
<div>
  <p>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
  <p class="uppercase">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
</div>

<div class="lc">
  <p>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
  <p class="uppercase">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe

*Updated with a `table` version since you had that in your question*

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 440px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  text-decoration: overline underline line-through;
}

table, th, td {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-decoration:overline underline line-through;
}
td:before,
td:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<span>
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
</span>
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> A </td>
    <td> B </td>
    <td> C </td>
    <td> D </td>
    <td> E </td>
    <td> F </td>
    <td> G </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> H </td>
    <td> I </td>
    <td> J </td>
    <td> K </td>
    <td> L </td>
    <td> M </td>
    <td> N </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> O </td>
    <td> P </td>
    <td> Q </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> U </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> V </td>
    <td> W </td>
    <td> X </td>
    <td> Y </td>
    <td> Z </td>
    <td> &nbsp; </td>
    <td> &nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```